# How / why does behavior of SQL*Plus BREAK depend on column order?

Tags: oracle, report, sqlplus

## Background

I'm familiar with databases but have never used Oracle in particular. In the process of trying to help someone with a homework assignment, I've hit a snag trying to understand the behavior of the `BREAK` command.  In particular, the results of using the `BREAK` command seem to depend on the order of the columns in the query I'm using, which as far as I can tell is not reflected in the documentation in any way.

## Setup for examples

I created a table where there are a couple of different colors, each with a few items of that color, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE products(product_id NUMBER, product_color VARCHAR(10), product_name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(1, 'Green', 'Green baseball cap');
INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(2, 'Green', 'Green shirt');
INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(3, 'Green', 'Grapes');
INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(4, 'Orange', 'Orange baseball cap');
INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(5, 'Orange', 'Traffic cone');
```

## Example displaying expected behavior

When I run the following commands,

```
CLEAR COLUMNS;
CLEAR BREAKS;
CLEAR SCREEN;

SET LINESIZE 120;

COLUMN product_color NOPRINT NEW_VALUE the_color;
BREAK ON product_color SKIP PAGE;

TTITLE CENTER the_color;

SELECT product_id, product_color, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;
```

This appears to produce reasonable output, with one "page" per color showing the color at the top and showing the relevant records below:

```
                                                        Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap  
         2 Green shirt         
         3 Grapes              

                                                        Orange  
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap 
         5 Traffic cone
```

## Seemingly-identical example exhibiting unexpected behavior

**However**, if I simply change the order of the columns in the query, i.e. replacing the last line of the script above with something like:

```
SELECT product_color, product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;
```

then the results are completely different, generating a page break after every single record for no apparent reason:

```
                                                        Green  
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap  

                                                        Green  
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         2 Green shirt         

                                                        Green  
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         3 Grapes              

                                                        Orange 
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap 

                                                        Orange 
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         5 Traffic cone
```

## Questions

- Why does changing the order of the columns in the query output result in different behavior from the `BREAK` statement?  (Or is the `BREAK` command a red herring, with the page breaks in the second example being created for some unrelated reason?)
- Is this actually documented somehow in the documentation, but in some way that I'm not understanding?
- Is there a term describing this behavior that I can search for to read more?
- Is there any better documentation for SQL*Plus than the official Oracle site?  It seems to be fairly spotty and rarely to unambiguously specify what the commands do.

## Possible leads

I have read through the documentation for the SQL*Plus `BREAK` command located at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve009.htm#SQPUG030 but I'm not seeing anything relevant to the order that columns appear in.

I thought the issue might potentially have something to do with suppression of duplicates interfering with the detection of the field changing, but adding `DUPLICATES` to the `BREAK` command has no effect.

Of the six possible permutations, it looks like the ones that cause a problem are the two where `product_color` is the first column.

Similarly, changing the query to something like

```
SELECT 1, product_color, product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;
```

produces the expected behavior, suggesting that perhaps the leftmost column plays some special role here.

Also, I have discovered that removing `NOPRINT` from the `COLUMN` command makes this behavior go away, for reasons I don't understand.

## Environment information

The oracle server reports that it is

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 21.2.1.204, Build 204.1703 to connect.

Comment: really good question. This is a really good example of how to ask ;) My vote for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `BREAK` in your example is not right. I update this post thanks to @Littlefoot, and is due to the fact that you are using a SqlDeveloper, a java tool not intended for this kind of reporting.

I created your table and insert the records in both databases, then running the reports you did.

**Demo 12cR2**

```
SQL> select banner from v$version ;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> CREATE TABLE products(product_id NUMBER, product_color VARCHAR(10), product_name VARCHAR(20));

Table created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(1, 'Green', 'Green baseball cap');

1 row created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(2, 'Green', 'Green shirt');

1 row created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(3, 'Green', 'Grapes');

1 row created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(4, 'Orange', 'Orange baseball cap');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(5, 'Orange', 'Traffic cone');

1 row created.
```

Now let's run the reports

```
SQL> CLEAR COLUMNS;
columns cleared
SQL> CLEAR breaks;
breaks cleared
SQL> COLUMN product_color NOPRINT NEW_VALUE the_color;
SQL> BREAK ON product_color SKIP PAGE;
SQL> TTITLE CENTER the_color;
SQL> SELECT product_id, product_color, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                      Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                     Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone

SQL> SELECT product_color, product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                      Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                     Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone
```

As you have seen, in 12.2 there is no unexpected behaviour in the `BREAK` command and it works as it should.

**Demo 19c**

```
SQL> select banner_full from v$version ;
                                                            
BANNER_FULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> CREATE TABLE products(product_id NUMBER, product_color VARCHAR(10), product_name VARCHAR(20));

Table created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(1, 'Green', 'Green baseball cap');

1 row created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(2, 'Green', 'Green shirt');

1 row created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(3, 'Green', 'Grapes');

1 row created.

INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(4, 'Orange', 'Orange baseball cap');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO products(product_id, product_color, product_name) VALUES(5, 'Orange', 'Traffic cone');

1 row created.
```

Now, let's run the reports

```
SQL> CLEAR COLUMNS;
columns cleared
SQL> CLEAR BREAKS; 
breaks cleared
SQL> COLUMN product_color NOPRINT NEW_VALUE the_color;
SQL> BREAK ON product_color SKIP PAGE;
SQL> TTITLE CENTER the_color;
SQL>  SELECT product_id, product_color, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                                          Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                                         Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone

SQL> SELECT product_color, product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                                          Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                                         Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone
```

So, same expected behaviour of the `BREAK` command.

### Answering your questions

*Why does changing the order of the columns in the query output result in different behaviour from the `BREAK` statement? (Or is the `BREAK` command a red herring, with the page breaks in the second example being created for some unrelated reason?)*

**It does not.** As I said before, such behaviour can't be reproduced neither in 12c nor 19c ( not in 11g as @Littlefoot shown ). I assure you that the normal behaviour of `BREAK` is not affected by the order.

*Is this actually documented somehow in the documentation, but in some way that I'm not understanding?*

**Not really**, as you understands how the command works but not the behaviour you are getting, which clearly is not reproducible in 12c or higher versions. I have no option to test nothing in 11g as that's a very old and unsupported version, but in the other answer from @Littlefoot, you can see that the behaviour is the same.

*Is there any better documentation for SQL*Plus than the official Oracle site? It seems to be fairly spotty and rarely to unambiguously specify what the commands do.*

The reference is the best you can find. Obviously, Oracle, as every other major software provider, is not perfect documenting. I can't blame them for that, honestly, as it happens everywhere. Actually, I do think they have one of the best ones.

**My advice: Use `sqlplus` and Upgrade your database. 11g was deprecated years ago. You can try with `sqlcl` the sql developer command line interface, but I never used against 11g, although I do think it should not be a problem**

By the way, regarding *I have discovered that removing NOPRINT from the COLUMN command makes this behaviour go away, for reasons I don't understand*.

> **PRINT|NOPRINT** Controls the printing of the column (the column heading and all the
> selected values). NOPRINT turns off the screen output and printing of
> the column. PRINT turns the printing of the column ON.

Not exactly. If you change `NOPRINT` by `PRINT`, it works as it should, so that you might print the column that is part of the `BREAK`. But, it only shows once in the results, because you break on it.

```
SQL> COLUMN product_color PRINT NEW_VALUE the_color;
SQL> SELECT product_id, product_color, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;
                                                          Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_CO PRODUCT_NAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 Green      Green baseball cap
         2            Green shirt
         3            Grapes

                                                         Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_CO PRODUCT_NAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
         4 Orange     Orange baseball cap
         5            Traffic cone
```

Hope this long answer help you somehow. Feel free to ask any question or doubt you might have. But I am quite sure that the reason is your version.

**UPDATE**

As @Littlefoot as stated in his answer below, the issue might be related with SQLDeveloper, which is a Java tool. I did not realize you were using SQL Developer, even though you can run scripts, it is not the same for those `sqlplus` specific reporting commands. I was relying in your documentation links to `sqlplus`, so naturally I assume you were using it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this 11g instance is what's provided by the school, and the assignments are required to run against it.  But knowing that this is likely a bug in a database version that was deprecated almost a decade ago is worthwhile information.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, another option ( I just updated ) is to install a client 12c and connect to the 11g database. Nevertheless, the school should not be doing this anyway. They must upgrade, I mean they are teaching, so they should be up to date

Comment: That said, re: the documentation I'm used to a lot more detailed information in my day-to-day work.  Compare the C++ standard, or the official documentation for Java or .NET.  They're all written in such a way that you can simulate the behavior of a program on paper and be 100% confident in the results.

Comment: I think trying to do stuff client-side is probably a no-go, given that it likely won't work when the grader tries to run the code using the school's client.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, you are right in that regard, but you can't expect that the documentation reference contain a behaviour which is not expected. I work with databases and by far Oracle has better documentation than any other. Of course, we enter here in the realm of opinions which is totally subjective.

Comment: anyway, just wanted to say again that I hope someone can put your question as an example on how to ask. Just for that I spent my time investigating the behaviour in two different databases and making the effort to put all that in an answer. #

Answer (score 3):

Strange. My environment is just the same as yours, and I don't see such a behaviour. I just removed `clear screen` from code you posted.

This is query that returns correct result for you (and for me).

**Client 11.2.0.2.0**

```
C:\Oracle\oraclexe112_64bit\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on ╚et Stu 11 08:03:58 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

---

```
SQL> CLEAR COLUMNS;
columns cleared
SQL> CLEAR BREAKS;
breaks cleared
SQL>
SQL> SET LINESIZE 120;
SQL>
SQL> COLUMN product_color NOPRINT NEW_VALUE the_color;
SQL> BREAK ON product_color SKIP PAGE;
SQL>
SQL> TTITLE CENTER the_color;
SQL>
SQL> SELECT product_id, product_color, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                                          Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                                         Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone

SQL>
```

Now, query that produces unexpected breaks in your database (but doesn't in mine), with `product_color` being the 1st column in `select` column list:

```
SQL> SELECT product_color, product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                                          Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                                         Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone

SQL>
```

---

I tried different clients as well, no problem:

**Client 11.2.0.1.0**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Stu 11 08:10:56 2021
  
SQL> CLEAR COLUMNS;
columns cleared
SQL> CLEAR BREAKS;
breaks cleared
SQL>
SQL> SET LINESIZE 120;
SQL>
SQL> COLUMN product_color NOPRINT NEW_VALUE the_color;
SQL> BREAK ON product_color SKIP PAGE;
SQL>
SQL> TTITLE CENTER the_color;
SQL>
SQL> SELECT product_color, product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                                          Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                                         Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone

SQL>
```

**Client 18.5.0.0.0**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Nov 11 08:12:20 2021
Version 18.5.0.0.0

SQL> CLEAR COLUMNS;
columns cleared
SQL> CLEAR BREAKS;
breaks cleared
SQL>
SQL> SET LINESIZE 120;
SQL>
SQL> COLUMN product_color NOPRINT NEW_VALUE the_color;
SQL> BREAK ON product_color SKIP PAGE;
SQL>
SQL> TTITLE CENTER the_color;
SQL>
SQL> SELECT product_color, product_id, product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_color;

                                                          Green
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap
         2 Green shirt
         3 Grapes

                                                         Orange
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap
         5 Traffic cone

SQL>
```

---

### I believe that this is crucial:

> I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 21.2.1.204, Build 204.1703 to connect.

**SQL Developer**. Me and Roberto used **SQL Plus**, Oracle's command-line tool.

When I tested your code that returns "invalid" result, so true!

```
columns cleared
breaks cleared

                                                        Green                                                         
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         1 Green baseball cap  

                                                        Green                                                         
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         2 Green shirt         

                                                        Green                                                         
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         3 Grapes              

                                                        Orange                                                        
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         4 Orange baseball cap 

                                                        Orange                                                        
PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_NAME        
---------- --------------------
         5 Traffic cone
```

It is **SQL Developer** that produces "wrong" result. It has nothing to do with the database version, but the *tool*.

So, what to do? Use SQL*Plus instead :) Or, download [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html), the newest command-line tool Oracle provides.

Comment: well catch! I updated my answer pointing to your comments. I was relying in the links to sqlplus in the question itself, so I assumed that he was using sqlplus. The tool was edited later, when I was writing the answer. Good to know you are always here my friend ;)

Comment: Ah, so SQL*Plus is the name of the _tool_, not the _language_, and the commands like `COLUMN` and `BREAK`  and so forth are run client-side?

Comment: Exactly, @Daniel. Language is "SQL". Tool is SQL Plus. BTW, to save you from further misery, I've just installed SQLcl so that you wouldn't have to. It also produces "wrong" result, so - the only way out is to install SQL Plus (or use workaround query you already found).